# Digits Phone number is blank even after success

Tags: android, twitter-digits

```
DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
digitsButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
  @Override
  public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
    // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful for "
          + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
    Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
  }
});
```

When I run above code I am getting Authentication successful mesaage but phoneNumber string is showing blank.

I am using same code from many days and it was working smoothly. Today i am getting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Digits had released 2.0 , so you have to update your code for that release.

Edit: I have tried with 2.0 too, but it does not work.

Comment: For me problem was i did not cleared the active session. But this is rarest of the rare  problem.